# can't run my own .desktop file

Tags: python, scripts, .desktop

I want to create a .desktop file to execute a python script.
Here's the code in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=/home/pc/Desktop/test/main.py
Terminal=false
```

I double click on the .desktop file but nothing happens. When I run the py script manually it opens and runs fine. 
What else do I need to do?

Comment: Is the script executable?

Comment: I tried `chmod +x path/to/py/file/main.py` with no difference

Comment: Do you mean the .desktop file or .py script? The .py script relies on Panda3D to run (unless you just want to check if it's marked as executable properly)

Comment: Hi Leo, apart from the `Encoding=UTF-8`, of which I am not sure it is still recognized (see: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) and seems unnecessary anyway, the file looks fine to me. @A.B. already asked you for the shebang and the script being executable. The best option would be if we could try out for ourselves, but I don't know if it is possible to share it with us?

Comment: I can certainly try to replicate the problem with a py file with no dependency to run. But I just noticed, if I set the`Exec` to `python something/main.py` instead of just `something/main.py` , it runs fine. Might this be all I needed? Can I do this safely?

Comment: ??? Then you had no she-bang in the file.

Comment: I dont know what a she-bang is. EDIT: Yeah, coming from Windows :p

Comment: @A.B. is right, either the shebang is missing/incorrect or the sctipt is not executable.

Comment: See @A.B. 's answer.

Comment: Common guy, read my answer :\ I wrote this 60 minutes ago.

Comment: I swear I didn't notice that part, then the whole answer disappeared for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I had the answer deleted in the meantime, because you said that nothing has helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A shot in the blue:**

- Make the file executable

  ```
  chmod +x /home/pc/Desktop/test/main.py
  ```
- If the script hasn't a GUI use

  ```
  Terminal=true
  ```
- Add a she-bang in the first line of `/home/pc/Desktop/test/main.py`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  ```

  or

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  ```
- **If** you don't want the she-bang, start via

  ```
  Exec=python /home/pc/Desktop/test/main.py
  ```

Comment: The script has GUI. But I tried that anyway with no luck. I also tried doing chmod +x on the py file, still no change. I tried some other py files (not mine). They seem to work, so somethings up...

Comment: It was the  she-bang...